# Show that $\left\{\frac{1}{n^3-n+1}\right\}$ is a subsequence of $\{1/n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $\left\{\frac{1}{n^3-n+1}\right\}$ is a subsequence of $\{1/n\}$

Attempt:

We know that if $\{a_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{{a_{n_k}}\}$ then the sequence of indices $\{n_k\}$ should be strictly monotonic increasing. **I have already shown that it is monotonic incresing** i.e  $n_{k+1}>n_k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ where $a_n=1/n$, and $n_k=k^3-k+1$.

My request is to help me to complete the proof perfectly.

Comment: Consider the derivative of $f (x) = x^3 - x + 1$.

Comment: More precise: you can show that x^3 - x + 1 is increasing, so its reciprocal is decreasing and clearly takes natural values, so your sequence is a_(f (n)).

Comment: @ArthurSinulis derivative  for what reason, to show m.i . I have already shown it.

Comment: Just to be complete, note that you also have to observe that each term of the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n^3-n+1}\right\}$ is a term of the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}.$ After all, there are lots of strictly increasing sequences of real numbers that are NOT subsequences of $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ (so just showing "strictly increasing" is not sufficient). However, this part should not be very difficult!

Comment: @user1942348 So, what is missing in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete your proof, just remark that $n^3-n+1$ is a positive integer for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Definition.** Given a sequence $\{p_n\}_n$ of real numbers, a sequence $\{q_k\}_k$ is a subsequence if $q_k = p_{\beta(k)}$ for some strictly increasing function $\beta\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ok. $n^3-n+1=n(n-1)(n+1)+1>0$ as $n\geq 1$. But we also have to show that order of $\{{a_{n_k}}\}$ is preserved? How to show that?

Comment: You did it already! $\beta (k) = k^3-k+1$.